# JSON data in spring model

Tags: json, spring-mvc, datatables

Its a spring based web application. I have a data table in the screen. In my understanding, data table accepts only data in JSON format. so i have a field(String) in my model for holding data table data, the same will be hidden in the screen. Upon listing(form submit not ajax), I would serialize the list to JSON data and keep it in the model. In Javascript, I would populate the data table using the data in the hidden field. It works fine but i have a doubt like whether it is a correct approach ?

I have a export to excel functionality. I would pass the model in the ajax call and get the data from the model and create the XLSX file. Issue is if the data has 3000 records, it works fine but when the record get increases say 4000 the data in the model is coming as null in the handler. Is there any data size limit for the Spring to bind the value to model ?

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, the approach which you are following is correct.
For Export Excel functionality, you can pass the same JSON string which you stored in a hidden variable. And DE-serialize the JSON string to the data. Since JSON is just a string, there is no such limit on Ajax form data